# Is "¿Nos juntemos?" well said?

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, conjugación, preguntas, conversación

Someone asked me "¿Nos juntemos?" meaning if I would like to hang out with him in the near future.

I found the expression weird. I thought it should be "¿Nos juntamos?"

Comment: Yes, it is *grammatically correct*. How common it is to say that may depend on regional differences. Where is your friend from who said this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I wouldn't say "¿Nos juntemos?" to ask someone to meet me. Although "juntemos" is the subjunctive form of the verb and therefore it expresses a possibility or a desire, it's not used that way.

The right way to say that is "¿Nos juntamos?".

However, you could use that expression in a non-interrogative way, like in this one:

> Ojalá nos juntemos

Which means "I hope we could meet".

Answer (score 3):

This is oddly put.

If it’s going to use a subjective inflection, it should probably be *¡Juntémonos!* as a first-person imperative for a reflexive verb. That would mean ”Let’s get together!”

But then there’s the question mark, which makes it not an imperative at all and which leads to an indicative as you would expect in a question. So that should run along the lines of *¿Nos juntamos mañana?*  You don’t use subjunctive for questions like this.

Compare *¿Nos vamos?* and *¿Nos vemos?* with *¡Vámonos!* and *¡Veámonos!* to see what I mean.